# function becomes non-iterable when using a global variable inside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

beginner here, im interested in solving the problem but also learning the 'how' and 'why' of it

so i have this function:

```
import random

move = 0

def computer_move():
    global move
    if move == 0:
        while True:
            rand = random.randrange(0, 9)
            if positions[rand].state:
                move = 1
                positions[rand].state = False
                positions[rand].played = 'circle'
                return positions[rand].x,positions[rand].y
```

before i had the 'move' variable declared outside the function everything worked fine except whenever the function is called the variable reset to 0, so i had to  declare it outside and naturally i had to use it with `global`.
except now when i call the function like so:

```
x, y = computer_move()
```

i get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` on the line of the function call

i tired a few ideas but nothing seems to work. Appreciate any help or clarification

Comment: functions are never iterable. The *return value* of a function may be iterable. Notice, in your function, it is possible for your function to return `None`, which is what is happening. Think about what your function returns if `move != 0`....

Comment: This error means your function returned None, so the function finished without the return line being called... maybe you want to unindent the return line?

Comment: Note, you shouldn't be using a global variable here.

Comment: What is the function supposed to return when `move == 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a function returns `None` if no `return` is executed. Your function may return `None` like this if `move != 0`. In such a case, `x, y = computer_move()` will be equivalent to `x, y = None`, which is causing the `TypeError`.

Comment: This explains why the error happens, but not how to fix it. To solve that we need to know what the function is supposed to return in this case.